# How can I view online all of my phone contacts that Android synced to my google account?

Tags: sync, water-damage

We have an option in Android that allows us to sync/backup all our contacts to our google account. I did this and then later my phone got damaged and I can't switch it on again.

I would now like to view the contacts that were synced to my google account. Is there anyway I can do this online?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to see them within [GMail](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#contacts) or your Google account [here](https://www.google.com/contacts/)

Comment: Strange. All of my phone contacts are present under "Other contacts". But more surprisingly none of them have their phone numbers present. They're all just email addresses.

Comment: Same thing. Why are my contacts (phone numbers) not synced?